# Time.zone & in_time_zone display wrong time in views

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, time

So I'm getting some inconsistent results from dates in my view when I've set the Time.zone. I'm hoping someone can tell me what is going on. I've got ruby on rails app running on an ubuntu server 12.04

In my application controller I have a before_filter setting the Time.zone from the current_user's company's time_zone record.

```
before_filter :set_user_time_zone

private

def set_user_time_zone
  Time.zone = current_user.company.time_zone if user_signed_in?
end
```

The user I'm testing with is in the "Central Time (US & Canada)"

the raw database record is 2012-08-13 20:10:54

In my view I'm using the following code to format the date:

```
servicedata.service_last_run_time.strftime('%b %e, %Y %l:%M%P')
```

I would expect to return "Aug 13, 2012 8:10pm" which would be the above record in the "Central Time (US & Canada)" however I get "Aug 13, 2012 9:10am"

I tested the same code in rails console and it works fine. I'm unsure of why its not working.

Before I found the idea for the before_filter I was simply chaining "in_time_zone" in all of my views but getting the same results. Example

```
servicedata.service_last_run_time.in_time_zone(current_user.company.time_zone).strftime('%b %e, %Y %l:%M%P')
```

Again both Time.zone or manually chaining in_time_zone onto a date object worked fine in rails console but in the views return a horrible wrong time.

I tested the server is time to ensure they were unchanged UTC from the following:

```
Rails Console : 2012-08-14 02:06:29 +0000
Ubuntu Shell: Tue Aug 14 02:06:38 UTC 2012
```

I have no clue what I'm missing here.

Answer (score 0):

you want to use I18n.localize - see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html, specifically - http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#adding-date-time-formats

in config/locals/en.yml there are already a few builtin formats you can use, and you can add your own as well, so you can do

```
<%= I18n.localize(servicedata.service_last_run_time, :format => :long) %>
```

you can add your own in the config, just use the newly defined key in the format arg

```
<%= I18n.localize(servicedata.service_last_run_time, :format => :my_super_special_format) %>
```

note that you can write this 4 different ways, they are all the same when you are in a rails view

```
<%= I18n.localize(servicedata.service_last_run_time, :format => :long) %>
<%= I18n.l(servicedata.service_last_run_time, :format => :long) %>
<%= localize(servicedata.service_last_run_time, :format => :long) %>
<%= l(servicedata.service_last_run_time, :format => :long) %>
```

if the datetime value is nil it will throw an exception (unfortunate) so if nil is valid add some conditionals

```
<%= localize(servicedata.service_last_run_time, :format => :long) if servicedata.service_last_run_time %>
```

Comment: the `I18n.localize` method is aware of the `Time.zone` setting in your controller, it knows how to make the adjustment from UTC to Time.zone - have you tried it?

Answer (score 0):

And I worked out what was wrong. It wasn't my method for displaying the date in the time_zone

Unknown to me the record I was trying to display was from a computer report and when that computer reports its grabs the current timezone of the machine.

So I was trying to take a time already in central and converting it again. oops.